# Grab div by ID and apply inline style

Tags: javascript

I have a div with the `id="playerViewer"`.

In some situations I want to change the styles of this div, I try to do it this way:

```
  if (include(urlarr, listen)) {
        //$('#playerViewer').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '5px').css('right', '100px'); I Don't want to use Jquery
        document.getElementById("playerViewer").style.position="fixed";
        document.getElementById("playerViewer").style.top="5px";
        document.getElementById("playerViewer").style.right="100px";
        alert("No alert showing up, even though the function is true");
};
```

In my console I got:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

So I guess I am doing using `getElementById` wrong - can someone point me in the right direction?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="playerViewer">
    <div id="defaultVideocontainer">
        <div id="defaultVideopart">
        <video id='dago_video' class='jwplayer dago-video'  width='480' height='360' controls ></video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your complete HTML code.

Comment: provide more information and HTML, may be a fiddle

Comment: Are you using Asp.net with master page ?

Comment: only reason I'm seeing is when the script is executed the div may not have loaded to the dom

Comment: You may using this script at top of the document body.

Comment: Is the DIV dynamically loaded? Are you calling the if statement after the DOM is ready?

Comment: How could I make sure that it is loaded to DOM? When viewing source the DIV is there? But it is hidden visually until someone clicks the play button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wheter you can access a div has nothing todo wheter it's hidden via css (e.g. `display:none`).

You could try to execute the code when the page has loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (include(urlarr, listen)) {
        document.getElementById("playerViewer").style.position="fixed";
        document.getElementById("playerViewer").style.top="5px";
        document.getElementById("playerViewer").style.right="100px";
  };
}
```

If you execute it before, the div has not been created / cannot get accessed.